# CodeIgniter: OS Command Injection

Tags: php, codeigniter-2, code-injection

Is there a way in CodeIgniter to prevent OS command injection automatically? I am aware of all the other protection CI has, but cannot find any material about OS Command Injection.

**EDIT after comments received:**

We are developing a web app that we are developing, will be hosted inside a large internal network where they have strict security policies that we will need to adhere to. One of them is OS Command Injection protection. They are afraid that users will run OS Commands through input fields. Is this possible, and how do I prevent this?

Comment: I don't think CodeIgniter has a built-in class to run shell commands, so it wouldn't have this.  Take a look at [`escapeshellarg`](http://php.net/escapeshellarg) and [`escapeshellcmd`](http://php.net/escapeshellcmd).  Depending on what you are doing, the [security class](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/security.html) might be useful.

Comment: Are you actually executing user-supplied input in a shell? If not, you don't need to worry about this.

Comment: No, but a webapp that we are developing, will be hosted inside a large internal network where they have strict security policies that we will need to adhere to. One of them is OS Command Injection protection. They are afraid that users will run OS Commands through input fields. Is this possible, and how do I prevent this? I will update the question accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CodeIgniter doesn't run shell commands, which is a pretty easy way to prevent command injection. If you are *adding* shell command execution to the web app you are creating you will need to take care of preventing command injection yourself.

Comment: Thank you. This allows me to complete the document as requested by the client.

Answer (score 0):

CodeIgniter has features for preventing SQL Injection but not Command Injections. There are 3 ways to prevent attack from url:

1. Set limited user permission to runs web application. Make sure he won't be able to write or execute out of control.
2. Disable php functions in disable_functions in php.ini.
3. Install Suhosin 수호신 which is a PHP security extension and stop eval(). Because eval() is a construct not a function, you cannot disable with disable_functions in php.ini.

Check my command injection attack in [Check And Solve If Your QNAP NAS Has been Injected a CPUMiner Program](https://amigotechnotes.wordpress.com/2017/05/03/check-and-solve-if-your-qnap-nas-has-been-injected-a-cpuminer-program/). It contains not only shell_exec() but also eval().